# Export an Excel file stored in an Access table in a OLE field to a folder

Tags: excel, vba, ole

I have an excel file stored in an Access table. I want to be able to select a folder and extract that file into the selected folder, all in VBA. I have the folder selection part complete and the selection of the field in the table via a RecordSet also complete. What I do not have is how to save the file to the selected path.

```
sub ExportEmbededFiles()

Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim oleObj As OLEObject

strFolderPath = SelectFolder("Select Folder to Export File to...")
'strFolderPath = "C:\Temp\"  'used for testing
Debug.Print strFolderPath



Set oleObj = New OLEObject

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM  [Excel Template]")

If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
    Debug.Print "no records in table"
    rstTemp.Close
    dbs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Else
        With rs
            .MoveFirst 'rs
              Do While Not .EOF 'rs
              'this is where im stuck....
              Set oleObj = rs!File
              'save the embeded file to the path given above in 
              'oleObj.Save (strFolderPath)
            .MoveNext ' rs
            Loop
        End With
End If

rs.Close
dbs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the DAO method GetChunk.  You write a loop to read a certain chunk size from the field, then you can append it to a file, and keep doing that until the total file size is reached.  Here's some documentation: http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fkb%2F194975&ei=VaKgU4GOHpD68QXk3IHADQ&usg=AFQjCNGKQ_0i1ILosMlG3MO8zXxRhFjrAg and an example: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/680306-how-export-access-blobs-images-files

Comment: thanks for that i'll have a look through the code....i was hoping for an easier way...im surprised that something like this isnt easier to do i.e. in a few lines of code...

Comment: im still having problems...any chance anyone can provide some working sample code?

Answer (score -1):

You can export files stored as OLE to a folder using the free Invantive Query Tool (I'm involved with it) as follows:

```
select olecolumn
from table

local export documents in <COLUMN-NAME> to "<DIRECTORY>" filename (automatic|column <COLUMN-NAME>) actions onerrorcontinue, extractole1
```

Please note that there are various OLE flavours around. This only works for OLE1 format. When exporting more than a few GB of OLE files in one batch, please ensure sufficient physical memory present.

Comment: the answer provided is absolute gibberish.

Comment: How can I help you to make it non-gibberish?